# Como integro SweetAlert a mi consulta PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Tengo un formulario y cuando hago clic en registrar deseo que me muestre un alerta de éxito en la inserción o error al no poder insertar.
Con el codigo que muestro tampoco me muestra las alertas ( alert("Ingrese Informacion");), esto funcionaba bien hasta que agregue la linea header('Location: registro.php'); para resetear mi formulario html.

```
<?php 
require_once 'conexion2.php';

?>
<?php 
$btnconsulta="";

if (isset($_POST["xNombre"], $_POST["xApellido"], $_POST["xCorreo"]) and $_POST["xCelular"] !="" and $_POST["xArea"]!="" and $_POST["xDocumento"]!="" and $_POST["xDetalles"]!=""){
    require_once 'conexion2.php';  
    $NOM=$_POST["xNombre"];
    $AP=$_POST["xApellido"];
    $COR=$_POST["xCorreo"];
    $CEL=$_POST["xCelular"];
    $AREA=$_POST["xArea"];  
    $DOC=$_POST["xDocumento"];
    $DETALLE=$_POST["xDetalles"];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO expediente (Apellidos,Nombres,Correo,Celular,Area,Tipo,Detalle) VALUES ('$AP','$NOM','$COR','$CEL','$AREA','$DOC','$DETALLE')";
    if(mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)){
         mysqli_close($conexion);
        echo '<script>
        alert("Se registro con exito")  ;
        </script>'; 
       header('Location: registro.php');
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conexion);
        header('Location: registro.php');
    }
    } else{
        echo '<script>
        alert("Ingrese Informacion");
    
        </script>'; 
       header('Location: registro.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: Quita las redirecciones y, en caso de éxito, reinicias el formulario: [`document.getElementById('myform').reset();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset)

Comment: Disculpe, soy nuevo en esto, ¿donde coloco esa linea de codigo?

Comment: Edita la pregunta, elimina las redirecciones y agrega el código que usas para la petición AJAX.